# GSON conversion throws "failed making field [package] accessible" error

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, gson

I have a Servlet code which I am running to query data from MySQL and converting it to a json object with gson. Ultimately I want to use axios in my react app to show this in the frontend. I am always running into problems with GSON though and it's never compiling correctly. Earlier it was version 2.8 so I upgraded to 2.9 to remove the reflection error, but now I am getting this error.

> com.google.gson.JsonIOException: Failed making field
> 'java.lang.ref.Reference#referent' accessible; either change its
> visibility or write a custom TypeAdapter for its declaring type

My servlet program code:

```
package org.datafetching;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.sql.*;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

@WebServlet("/fetchdata")
public class FetchData extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public FetchData() {
    }
    
    
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }
    
    
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/grey_goose", "", "");
            PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("select * from table limit 10");
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String tablejson = gson.toJson(rs);
            
            PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            printWriter.print(tablejson);
            printWriter.flush();

            //printWriter.write(tablejson);
            
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Object class code

```
package servdemo.registration.model;

public class Employee {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String address;
    private String contact;
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public String getContact() {
        return contact;
    }
    public void setContact(String contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should create an object which will represent your table, then map result set into it. Then you will be able to parse it to json. You shouldn't parse result set

Comment: Oh I did not know that. Could you point me to a sample code if possible, I'm still a beginner in backend

Comment: Look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should map result set to an Object which represent a table. For example if you have table named People and it have field name and age.

Example class

```
public Class People {
  private String name;
  private Integer age;
  ... //Getters and Setters here
}
```

And here is code for mapping data.

```
List<People> staffs = new ArrayList<People>();
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
while (resultSet.next()) {
  People people = new People(resultSet.getString("name"),
                             resultSet.getInt("age"));
  staffs.add(people);
}
resultSet.close();
preparedStatement.close();
connection.close();
Gson gson = new Gson();

String yourJson = gson.toJson(staffs);
```

This code will map your result set. Of course you need to create object based on your table so after changing this code a bit you should make it work.

Comment: Oh I get it now. I am assuming I have to make a separate .java for the public class right? I have attached a sample code of that, can you tell me if it'd be something like that?

Comment: yes, exactly. You need to make class for each response you want to make from your api. If this answers your question please mark answer as best answer.

Comment: Yeah sure, thanks a lot for the help!